# Determine if a control is showing

Tags: delphi

Lets say I have a pagecontrol with two tabsheet. There is a button on the first sheet but the active sheet is the second. In this case how can I determine if that button is showing (e.g. visible for the user) or not?
I tried the button's Showing property, but for some reason its always True.

**update:** for the clarification I don't mind if the control is outside of the desktop's visible area or covered by any other application's window.

Comment: And what if the first sheet is the active one but the user moves the window so that the button ends up outside of the desktop's visible area?

Comment: Good question, thanks. It does not matter in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply go up in the VCL tree until you find an element which isn't visible, or you have no other parent to check.

```
function IsVisible(Obj:TWinControl):boolean;
begin
  Result:=Obj.Visible;
  if not Obj.Visible then Exit;

  while Obj.HasParent do
  begin
    Obj:=Obj.Parent;
    Result:=Obj.Visible;
    if not Result then Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: No need for the last line.

Comment: omg, I didn't even tried to check the Visible property of the TabSheet, I feel ashamed now :) thanks a lot.

Comment: applied Andreas' comment, indeed last line is not needed

Comment: I guess I could use CanFocus too, if I dont care about the Enabled property, right?

Comment: @tcxbalage You can check any propety you need that TWinControl has with this method.